# Questions about a finite $p$-group in a paper

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

In the proof  of Theorem 1 of the paper,

The number of conjugacy classes of non-normal cyclic subgroups in nilpotent groups of odd order,
Journal of Group Theory. Volume 1, Issue 2, Pages 165-171,

pages 167-169, $G$ is a finite nilpotent group and $\nu^*(G)$ and $\Phi(G)$ denote the number of 
 conjugacy classes of non-normal cyclic subgroups of  $G$ and the Frattini subgroup of $G$, respectively.
I have the following questions in steps (e) and (f) in this proof:

1. In part (e), the author says that "$\frac{G}{\langle u^p\rangle}$ satisfies the assumption of the theorem."
   Why do we have $\nu^*(\frac{G}{\langle u^p\rangle})=1$? (According to Lemma 1 of this paper,
   I know that $\nu^*(\frac{G}{\langle u^p\rangle})\leq \nu^*(G)=1$. Now why do we have $\nu^*(\frac{G}{\langle u^p\rangle})\neq 0$?)

   2. By induction hypothesis we have $\frac{G}{\langle u^p\rangle}\cong M(p^n)$. 
      Why do we have $x^p\in \langle u^p\rangle$?
   3. In part (f), the author has concluded that  $\nu^*(G)=\nu^*(H)=1$. 
      How could we conclude it from this fact that $U$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group of order $p^2$?

Thank you so much for your thought on my questions! Here is the proof of the Theorem

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For you first question: each group has a neutral element. This element forms its own conjugacy class, so a group always has at least 1 conjugacy class: $\{e}\$, where $e$ denotes the neutral element.

Comment: The complete reference is *Li, Shirong. The number of conjugacy classes of non-normal cyclic subgroups in nilpotent groups of odd order. J. Group Theory 1 (1998), no. 2, 165-171.*